# How do I dissmiss keyboard when I touch outside UISearchBar using swift code

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uisearchbar

How do I dissmiss keyboard when I touch outside UISearchBar using swift code. It works when I'm on the google search page but when I'm inside of a website and I touch the uisearchbar then when I tap outside of it the keyboard does not disappear.

Here my code so far.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!



func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {


    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()


    var text = searchBar.text
    text = text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+");
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/search?q=".stringByAppendingString(text));
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req)


}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)

    self.searchBar.delegate = self

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use touch event to dissmiss keyboard

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just inserted that before you responded. It works now. Do you know where I can study swift